# How to declare an array that is received like parameter in a function that also receive a pointer to a function in C?

Tags: arrays, c, pointers, function-pointers

How to declare an array that is received like an parameter in a function that also receive a pointer to a function in C and that function is using the values from the array?
The function that use the values from the array doesn't receive a parameter.
It's something like:

```
int find_array(void)
```

and the function that receive this function like parameter also receive the array. I think that declaration should look something like:

```
int function ( int (*pmin)(void), int* array )
```

How the function `find_array` knows that it should work with the array received like parameter? How to declare this array?

Comment: If the function doesn't receive the array as a parameter it has no way to know what array it should work with (except when using global variable --- and global variables are bad). C has no support for ["closures"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Closure_(computer_programming)).

Comment: do you mean `void fun(int arr[], int size, int operation(int))` ?

Comment: can we use typedef in a way?

Comment: int function should receive just 2 parameters, a pointer to function find_array and the array. I should also to find a way to declare the size of the array

Comment: Don't fight the language Cezar. Pass along the number of elements in the array. Don't create functions that work on an array but do not receive arguments. If you really need to use those features maybe try a newer language??

Comment: How should `find_array()` work, when it has no arguments? How do you plan to hand over the values of the array? BTW, one at a time, or all at once?

Comment: Cezar, Functions cannot have arrays as parameters.  A parameter could be a pointer, but not an array.

Comment: Type definitions are nice for clean code. You need to understand them before you use them. They are no silver bullet.

Comment: can we use macros to define the size of the array ?and to pass the array like a pointer, to pass the address of the first element from the array

Comment: "can we use macros to define the size of the array?" Yes, but the macros will not work when the "array" is a pointer (will not work inside a function that was passed a pointer). Unless you encapsulate the array inside a `struct` there is no way to pass an array to a function (which you really don't want to do anyway).

Comment: The only way I can see that this could work is if `function` assigns the array to a global pointer variable, which `find_array()` uses.

Comment: Again, macros are not always good solutions. They are the root cause of many hard-to-find-but-nasty bugs in code, especially for beginners.

Comment: You either pass the array and the number of items as parameter, or you pass some kind of struct that points to the array and knows the number of items. Unless you are only working with hard-coded data-sources, NO, you cannot use a macro. If you want convenience, don't program in a low-level language.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> int function should receive just 2 parameters, a pointer to function
> find_array and the array.  I should also to find a way to declare the
> size of the array

It had to be extended to three parameters in order to give the size of the array:

```
#include <stdio.h>

// simple function working on an array
int find_minimum(int *array, int n) {
    int minimum = array[0];
    for (int i = 1; i < n; i++) {
        if (array[i] < minimum) {
            minimum = array[i];
        }
    }
    return minimum;
}

// function receiving an array and a function to process it
int function(int (*pmin)(int *array, int n), int *array, int n) {
    return pmin(array, n);
}

int main() {
    int array[] = {1, 2, -3, 4, 5};
    int min = function(find_minimum, array, sizeof array / sizeof(int));
    printf("minimum: %d\n", min);
return 0;
}
```

Looks good:

```
$ gcc -Wall -Werror array.c
$ ./a.out                  
minimum: -3
$
```

Regarding the parameter for the function to be give as parameter you might want to use ellipsis for a variable amount of parameters, see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ellipsis_(computer_programming).